# SQL query to get overlapping entries between two big lists of ranges

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database A with numeric columns for `start` and `stop` that is quite large (1M rows). And I have a second list of numeric ranges B `beginning` and `end` that is medium (10K rows).

I would like to find the set of entries in A that overlap with ranges in B.

I could do this with a python script that iterates through list B and does 10K database queries, but I'm wondering if there's a more SQLish way to do it. List B could potentially be slurped into the database as an indexed TEMP TABLE if that helps the process.

Possible simplification, though not optimal, is that list A could be treated as a single location, `position`, allowing us to only look for `A.position` that fall inside `B.beginning` and `B.end`.

Comment: What do you mean by overlap?  Partial or compete?

Comment: Either partial or complete should trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily express this in SQL as a join.  For partial overlaps, this would be:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a join
     b
     on a.start < b.end and a.end > b.start;
```

However, this will be slow, because it will be doing a nested loop comparison.  So, although concise, this won't necessarily be much faster.

Comment: That I didn't think about the JOIN option means I've been writing python too long. I'll give it a shot and see if the runtime is something I can live with.

Comment: I've rewritten using the BETWEEN command as: a.beginning BETWEEN b.start AND b.stop OR a.end BETWEEN b.start AND b.end. It seems to run in 'get a cup of coffee' time. But I think I can live with that. Especially if I so some optimizations moving various db files off network drives.

Comment: @AHolman . . . `BETWEEN` includes the endpoints.  One can reasonably disagree on whether that constitutes an overlap ;)

Comment: One could reasonably have a disagreement. Luckily the behavior of BETWEEN meets my requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One trick I use to speed this up is to define a CHUNK. This can be as simple as the midpoint of the start and end, divided by a chunksize and then cast as an integer. To build off @Gordon Linoff's answer, you could use a 10k window chunk as follows:

```
with a_chunk as (
    select a.*, cast((a.start+a.end)/(2*10000) as integer) as CHUNK
    from a
),
b_chunk as (
    select b.*, cast((b.start+b.end)/(2*10000) as integer) as CHUNK
    from b
)

select ac.*, bc.*
from a_chunk ac join b_chunk bc
     on ac.CHUNK = bc.CHUNK
     and ac.start < bc.end 
     and ac.end > bc.start;
```

This divides your search space so that rather than joining every row in `a` against every row in `b`, you're only joining entries within the same 10k-width window. This should still be an O(m*n) operation but will be considerably faster due to the restricted search space and smaller m/n sizes.

However, this comes with caveats. For instance, the intervals (9995, 9999) and (9998, 10008) will get placed in different chunks despite being clearly overlapping, and your resultant query would miss that. Therefore you can get your edge cases by replacing the single `select` statement with

```
select ac.*, bc.*
    from a_chunk ac join
         b_chunk bc
         on ac.CHUNK = bc.CHUNK - 1
         and ac.start < bc.end 
         and ac.end > bc.start
union
select ac.*, bc.*
    from a_chunk ac join
         b_chunk bc
         on ac.CHUNK = bc.CHUNK
         and ac.start < bc.end 
         and ac.end > bc.start
union
select ac.*, bc.*
    from a_chunk ac join
         b_chunk bc
         on ac.CHUNK = bc.CHUNK + 1
         and ac.start < bc.end 
         and ac.end > bc.start;
```

Even this isn't perfect though. If you have intervals significantly larger than your 10k window size, you could likely still overlook some results. Increasing the window size to accommodate this would come at the cost of joining more entries at a time, which the chunks were designed to avoid. The best balance will likely be finding an appropriate window size and then covering edge cases by including enough `UNION`s to include `on ac.CHUNK = bc.CHUNK + {-n...n}` for however large you think `n` should be.

Rather than using a CTE, you can also speed this up in SQLite by hard-coding `CHUNK` as a column in your tables and then creating clustered indexes on each table for `(CHUNK, start)`. You may or may not benefit from including `end` in this index as well, though you'll have to `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` on your specific case to see whether the optimizer actually does this. The trade-off, of course, is increased storage space, which may not be ideal depending on what you're trying to do.

This admittedly feels like a hack and I'm trying to answer a similar question for my own project. I've heard that the only efficient solution is to manually take the data and implement an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). However, with millions of rows, I'm not sure how efficient it would be to take this from sqlite and build a tree manually in your programming language of choice. If anyone has any better solutions I'd be happy to hear. At least in python, the [ncls](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/ncls) library seems like it could get the job done.